# I need to assign id to data from looping ajax call

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, function

I am working with 2 endpoints:

1. a list of location IDs
2. Location specific info (this endpoint requires the an id from the first at the end)

the second endpoint does not include location IDs but I need them to be part of the location information. I thought to somehow inject the ids into the Location info but I am stuck.

I do an call to retrieve the location IDs:

```
ar settings1 = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "wss_api/wss_api.php?method=hello&format=json",
    "dataType": "json",
    "method": "GET"
};

var a1 = $.ajax(settings1);

var en = [];

var rt = [];

$.when(a1).done(function(d1) {

    var d1p = JSON.parse(d1.data);

    $.each( d1p.Entities, function(i, id) {

        en.push({entity:id, url:"http://localhost/api_test/wss_api/locationdata.php?method=hello&format=json&entity=" + id});

    });

    makeMerge(en, d1p);

});
```

Here I push an object containing the id and the url (the the id at the end) to "en". I fire the makeMerge function with "en" and "d2" as parameters.

In the makeMerge function I have a function for the ajax calls, and do a forloop to push the function with the url and the id to "rt".

```
function makeMerge(en_urls, en_id) {

    function LocationData(d2, d3) {

        return $.ajax({
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "dataType": "json",
            "url": d2,
            "method": "GET"
        });
    }

    for (url in en_urls) {
        rt.push(LocationData(en_urls[url].url, en_urls[url].entity));
    }

    $.when.apply(this, rt).done(function () {

        var ld = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {

        });

    });
```

Then I perform the ajax calls.

The problem is that the ids go from the first ajax call (d1p.Entities) to the object containing the id and the url (en) to the makeMerge function's forloop (en_urls[url].entity) to a parameter in the LocationData Function (d3) and stops.

I would like to assign the ids to the data retrieved by their corresponding urls, and logically it seams like this should be done in the LocationData function so that as the ajax call is fired the id currently in use is assigned before moving on to the next one. I see this as the best way to ensure that the order isn't messed up (wrong ID assigned to data).

Can anyone think of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I used a for loop inside of my arguments for loop that loops through the ids and assigns the id if it's index matches the index of the argument.

```
$.when.apply(this, rt).done(function () {

        var ld = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {

            datap = $.parseJSON(arguments[i][0].data);      

            for (url in en_urls) {  

                if (url == i) {

                    datap.Location["Entity"] = en_urls[url].entity;

                }

            };

            values = datap.Location;

            ld.push(values);

        };
```